# How to remove spaces from string except those in quotes

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a string like this:

```
'Hello ' world  '. Hello world'
```

I need to remove spaces, but not inside quotes. For current string result should be:

```
Hello world. Hello world
```

Is any regular expression can help with this.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your problem as a perl-oneliner (you can see how it removes whitespace around the 1st *world*):

```
# echo "'Hello ' world  '. Hello world'" | perl -ne "print \$1 while /('[^']+'|[^' ]+)/g"
'Hello 'world'. Hello world'
```

Use the regex `/('[^']+'|[^' ]+)/g` in your ActionScript program and you have it.

The key part of the regex is `[^']` which means: *match any character except single quote*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
('.*?').*?\s*(\w+)\s*
```

Check the Substitution on this **[working demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ1hJ8/2)**

Comment: Thanks Fede. But it not work with string like this: `concat('Hello ',      zerofill(5,5,'0'),     ' world')`

Comment: @YBorys fixed. Check this `('.*?').*?\s*(\w+)\s*`. Btw, since I don't know what are your posible strings I need to improve the regex progressively

Comment: Is it possible to have pattern which works in all cases?
But using first part of pattern `('.*?')`, i can find all quoted occurencies, memorize them, replace them with random unique strings without spaces, then remove all spaces and return to random strings they prevoius values.

Comment: @YBorys yup you can do that, but I answered based on your question providing a regex that can help you doing that. But of course, is up to you to implement the code. If you want to use full regex then my answer does it.

Comment: -1 because the suggested regex does not work in general cases - it only matches the particular string in the question. For example `'a ' ' b '` breaks it.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber as you said my answer is for this question. If OP had provided your case I would have used a different regex.